# How to get errors in pure string from ansible

Tags: ansible

I am running a simple ansible playbook as

```
---
- hosts: "{{ host }}"

  remote_user: "{{ ansible_user }}"



  tasks:
    # - name: Move Network for peer
    #   copy: 
    #     src: ./../network/
    #     dest: /home/{{ user }}/network/
    - name: Set JAVA_HOME
      blockinfile:
        path: /etc/environment
        backup: yes
        state: present
        block: |
          Match User ansible-agent
          PasswordAuthentication 4
      become: yes
```

So when running this ansible using comand

```
ansible-playbook -i ./inventory_yaml/single_host_inventory.yaml ./playlist/mytest.yaml --extra-vars "{\"host\":\"192.168.0.39\"}"
```

I am getting the error result as

```
PLAY [192.168.0.39] ************************************************************

TASK [Gathering Facts] *********************************************************
ok: [192.168.0.39]

TASK [Set JAVA_HOME] ***********************************************************
fatal: [192.168.0.39]: FAILED! => {"changed": false, "module_stderr": "Shared connection to 192.168.0.39 closed.\r\n", "module_stdout": "sudo: a password is required\r\n", "msg": "MODULE FAILURE", "rc": 1}
        to retry, use: --limit @/home/pankaj/go/src/ConfigTool/Go/playlist/mytest.retry

PLAY RECAP *********************************************************************
192.168.0.39               : ok=1    changed=0    unreachable=0  failed=1
```

So now how can i get message "sudo: a password is required" as a output from above command .

Thanks in advance .

Comment: The more general question here is the optimal method for parsing JSON output for Ansible tasks after recognizing that an error occurred for one of the tasks. Is there a known solution for that?

Answer (score 1):

Not entirely sure what you want, but you can set `ignore_errors`, capture the results, and add a `fail` task:

```
- name: Set JAVA_HOME
  blockinfile:
    path: /etc/environment
    backup: yes
    state: present
    block: |
      Match User ansible-agent
      PasswordAuthentication 4
  become: yes
  register: command_result
  ignore_errors: true

- name: fail if the previous command did not succeed
  fail:
    msg: "{{ command_result.module_stdout }}"
  when: command_result.failed == true
```

That's about the best you can clean it up.